# Google Analytics Filter--Need to Return Null Values Only

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I am trying to query Google Analytics and include only the results from users who are not logged in.

I am storing the User-ID in a custom dimension and I can filter by that custom dimension just fine (ga:dimension3==SOMEID)

I presume that the User-ID is null for users who are not logged in (let me know if this is a bad assumption).

Google's documentation doesn't explain how to filter by null values only:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Is it possible to filter out all non-null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter in Analytics only something that has a value (at least `(not set)`), you can for example send a custom dimension like `loggedIn` or `loggedOut` if the user is logged in or not and filter with those two strings, but if you only send `loggedIn` you can't get the `loggedOut` results because it is something that is not there.